# Subsonic 3 Newtonsoft JSON "Self referencing loop Exception"

Tags: linq, subsonic3, json.net

Hi I been searching for my error but I can't find anything that help me. The problem is this. I been working with Subsonic 3, Newtonsoft Json and the linq way of write so I have this easy query:

```
var found = from client in newclients.All() where client.Period == "sometext" select client;

string periodoJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(periodoFound); //this get "Self referencing loop Exception"
```

the problem is when I run this script I get the horrible exception "Self referening loop exception" in the JsonConvert line, subsonic have all the objects without any problem but if I do the following.

```
var found = from client in newclients.All() where client.Period == "sometext" select new client{client.Name, client.LastName, etc};

string periodoJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(periodoFound);
```

I get the object serialize with a any problem with all the properties. I'm doing the last way because I have to finish my work but is any other way or solution for this problem, if not I will have to write all the properties every time I want to get a full table properties.

hope any can solve my problem o help me in the path for find a solution....

---

what I have is a really basic query with linq and I try the three values for JsonSerializerSettings and any work, again I'm working with subsonic 3 this not happend either with subsnoic 2 and I can make it work if I specify one by one the properties of the object in the linq query does any have any clue of what is happend, ANY more help would be great!!! If I put the value of Serialize my page get crazy and in a infinity loop state, if I decide for error simple doesn't work and Ignore nothing happen... some more information about this self referencia loop?

```
var u = usuario.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TipoUsuario == "A" || x.TipoUsuario == "W");
JsonSerializerSettings setting = new JsonSerializerSettings();
setting.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Error; //.Serialize .Ignore

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"usuario", "var usuario=" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(u, Formatting.None, setting) + ";");
```

Update ------

I code the following

```
string jsU = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(u,Formatting.None,new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
```

and is workign but the only thing wrongs is that in the json object comes all the information about the columns of subsonic 3 and a BIG chunk of text explain it... does any one know how to not SEND this part of the object??

Comment: is my way or write and is not forbidden or rude, is like when somebody speak loud, you don't say him that don't speak cause that in that way is his voice, same for this, exclamation give a sense of way a person is, not inverse... sorry if you get offense, but in the way you are doing is a kind of censorship "is suppression of speech or other communication which may be considered objectionable, harmful, sensitive, or inconvenient to the general body".

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing more about you object model it is hard to provide a definitive answer, but I would take a look at the `ReferenceLoopHandling` enum.

You're calling `string SerializeObject(object value)` on `JsonConvert`. Try the `string SerializeObject(object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)` method instead. The `JsonSerializerSettings settings` parameter lets you set a bunch of things, including the `ReferenceLoopHandling ReferenceLoopHandling { get; set; }` property.

You can try these values:

```
public enum ReferenceLoopHandling
{
    Error,
    Ignore,
    Serialize
}
```

Obviously, `Error` is the default and that's what you're getting. Perhaps one of the others will help.

Comment: cool thanks for the answer and the time let me check it... :)

Comment: Im been working I can't available to check the suggestion... :P but I will... in next days...

Comment: is not working I have already check it... does any more idea will be great :)